# How to enumerate resources inside XPS file?

Tags: c#, xps

How can I access/read Resources inside an XPS package?

```
using (var doc = new System.Windows.Xps.Packaging.XpsDocument(filename, System.IO.FileAccess.Read))
{
    // how to read XpsResources? 
    // like XpsFont, XpsImage,... ?      
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the following MSDN pages:

[XpsDocument.FixedDocumentSequenceReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.xps.packaging.xpsdocument.fixeddocumentsequencereader.aspx) and [IXpsFixedPageReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.xps.packaging.ixpsfixedpagereader.aspx)

There are some code snippets there which should help with what you need, as well as looking at the [IXpsFixedPageReader Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.xps.packaging.ixpsfixedpagereader_properties.aspx).